# What javascript method do I use to run a function once every 24 hours?

Tags: javascript, database

I want to check my database once every 24 hours and delete posts that are past a certain date. I'm assuming I use setTimeout some how, but can I use that to get a function to run on it's own regularly? Does anyone have a link to an example of how to do this?

Comment: Is this for node.js ? Or for browser-side JS? For Node, I'd just use a cron job.

Comment: You'd be better off with a Cron task.

Comment: This is more suited to a cron job.

Comment: This question isn't useful without some additional tags telling us which technologies you're using.

Comment: to reiterate, this is a cron job (nix) or task scheduler (windows)

Comment: Use setInterval (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: It's for browser side JS. I'm not sure what additional technologies I should be mentioning. This is straight forward javascript. If setInterval is all I need then I'll use that. Thank you Igor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` should do the job. See the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_arg). I suppose, you use **node.js**.